# What are the stats to the exclusive pre-order bonus DLC Weapons/Armor?

Tags: mass-effect-3

It's not guaranteed that EA/Bioware will release the pre-order/exclusive DLC in a pack later down the line for users who didn't acquire it launch week.

What are the weapon and armor stats for the exclusive pre-order DLC, namely:

- AT-12 Raider
- Chakram Launcher
- M-55 Argus
- M-90 Indra
- N7 Collector's Edition Pack
- N7 Warfare Gear
- Reckoner Knight Armor

Comment: I pre-ordered.  How do I get the exclusive DLC?

Comment: http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3.  Scroll to Retail bonus items to figure out if you qualified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a spreadsheet with all known stats for all weapons in ME3, including the ones you mentioned:

[ME3Weapons](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aor1WdVV3kD6dGw1SlNDUzFjODlheGl5a3JLdXZZVXc#gid=0)